# XML FO: content ignores page right margin

Tags: xml, overflow, margin, xsl-fo

Have a small problem with my printed XSL FO document.
If text get's too long it ignores my right margin and overflows it's container.
All other margins are set fine (like top, bottom and left margin)
I already tried searching various posts but no working answer found yet.
What i tried already settings padding, margin and wrap-option?

Any idea where i'm going wrong

The output I get is the following, as you can see the last line exceeds the limit.
I placed a background color so I had a picture on if the right margin was taken credit of.

http://tinypic.com/r/11jz1j4/6

This is my code to set the margins of the page

```
<fo:root>
<fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="default" 
                       page-height ="297mm"
                       page-width  ="210mm" 
                       margin-left  ="3.17cm"
                       margin-right ="3.17cm" 
                       margin-top = "2.54cm"
                       margin-bottom = "2.54cm"    
                      >
<fo:region-body margin="0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm"/>
<fo:region-before extent=".5in"/>
<fo:region-after extent=".5in"/>
</fo:simple-page-master>
```

It's hard to give an example of my xml because it's originally html code that is converted into xml using java.

Comment: It will be a lot easier to answer your question if you post the smallest possible example that illustrates your problem.  As it is, the only possible answers are "No, no idea where you're going wrong", "your attempt to set the right margin is ok in principle but is failing for syntactic or semantic reasons", and "you're doing it wrong."  But you knew that already, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added a snippet of my fo XML code and a screenshot of the output. As you can see the last line overflows the right margin and the page.

Comment: What would have been useful six years ago would have been the markup for the `fo:block` that overflowed.